# Python function calling on linked list, call by value/call by reference

Tags: python, recursion, linked-list, pass-by-reference, call-by-value

below is the code for print a linked list

```
 def printlinkedlist(root):
  if root==None:
    return
  print(root.data)
  printlinkedlist(root.next)
```

Suppose the linked list contain

> 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8

by calling printlinkedlist(root) --------->it give out put as------>1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8

Now, i call another function

```
def linkedlist2(root):
  if root==None:
    return
  print(root.data)
  if root.next==None:
    root.data=50
    return
  linkedlist2(root.next)
```

Which basically make the last element value as 50.
when i called the function `printlinkedlist(root)` it produce `1-2-3-4-5-6-7-50`

doubt 1: since the value changed in orginal root, whether the root is passed by value or passed by reference?

Let hope it is passed by reference, if so

```
def linkedlist3(root):
  if root==None:
    return
  print(root.data)
  if root.next==None:
    root=None
    return
  linkedlist3(root.next)
```

which basically make the last node as None.ie, the `1-2-3-4-5-6-7-50` output should be like `1-2-3-4-5-6-7` (since 50 is maked as None) when call linkedlist(root). this is not what happend. it produce the same previous output, which is `1-2-3-4-5-6-7-50`.

Can some one please explain why my desired output not produced and whether it is happening as call by value or call by reference???.

Comment: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: In python objects are always referred to by their reference. Variables hold these references and themselves are copyable and reassignable. When a variable is passed as a parameter, it is copied and becomes a new variable. In `linkedlist3()` its `root` parameter is a new variable and `root = None` simply assigns a reference to `None` to that local variable.

Comment: All arguments in Python are passed by value, not by reference.  In the case of passing `root` to your linked list functions, `root` is a reference to a list, but it is *passed* by value.  So setting `root` to `None` immediately before returning has no effect, since all it does is set the local variable `root` to `None`.  The caller never sees that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a reference that is passed by value (i.e. it's similar to passing a pointer in C).

When you set `root.next` you are changing the value of `next` for the node that `root` refers to, and so the list changes at that node.  When you set `root` itself, you are only modifying the reference that was passed in, not the underlying value that it refers to, and so the list is unaffected.

If you want to remove the last node of a linked list, you need to set the `next` of the second-to-last node to `None`.  Something like:

```
def pop_last(root):
    if root is None or root.next is None:
        raise IndexError("can't pop from list with len < 2")
    if root.next.next is None:
        val = root.next.data
        root.next = None
        return val
    return pop_last(root.next)
```

Comment: Python doesn't support pass-by-reference.  It only supports pass-by-value.

Comment: The "value" itself is a reference.

Comment: Right.  It is a reference to a list, but it is *passed* by value.  Look at what OP asked:  Is is *passed* by reference.  It is not.  The correct answer is "no, it is passed by value."  There is a major distinction between passing a value by reference vs. passing a reference by value.

Comment: I guess the right phrasing is "it's a reference that's passed by value"...

Comment: Yes, exactly as I said.  Python does not support pass-by-reference argument passing.  It is always pass-by-value, even if the value is a reference.  If the called function changes the argument (as opposed to what it references), the caller never sees the change.